# What Custom Rom Alternatives Are Available To Users Of The Oppo Find 7a?

Tags: custom-roms, customization

For those who wish to try something other than the default ColorOS ?

Comment: @Izzy Although my question is very specific in nature.

Comment: As were all the others we've pointed to that specific (canonical) question. This site is about solving *issues* users have with Android – not about finding software or recommending specific ROMs. Furthermore, answers would be 1) very opinion-based, and 2) end up in lists. Both are closure reasons on almost every SE site, sorry. If you want to discuss opinions, you're better off on a forum than on a Q&A site; so one more pointer would be [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575)

Comment: @Izzy Is it suitable for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm afraid not, it's much too broad. SR doesn't cover questions of the type "please compare X,Y, and Z". So unless you can name specific requirements (for details, see [here](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)), it would be closed there as well.

Comment: @Izzy Alright :)